# Stern Taxi Fare plug-in - Google Direction API gives error

Tags: google-maps, google-api

A months ago, I bought a plug-in ([Stern Taxi Fare](http://stern-taxi-fare.sternwebagency.com/fr/home/)). The taxi calculator has always worked nicely and was always associated with Google API. For the past two days, when I connect, the plugin may or may not be using Google API and indicates an error in API directions. I turn on the debug mode and I get this error when it's not connecting.

-----------------------------DEBUG-----------------------------

```
object(stdClass) #2595 (3) { ["geocoded_waypoints"]= > array(2) {
    [0] => object(stdClass) #2581 (3) { ["geocoder_status"]= > string(2)
    "OK" ["place_id"] => string(27)
    "ChIJKSshOsWinkcRoOeL161IHgQ" ["types"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(8)
        "locality" [1] => string(9)
        "political"
    }
}[1] => object(stdClass) #2596 (3) { ["geocoder_status"]= > string(2)
"OK" ["place_id"] => string(27)
"ChIJR9PV36Zuv4cRuh8PH2dhM6A" ["types"] => array(1) {
    [0] => string(7)
    "premise"
}
}
}["routes"] => array(0) {}["status"] => string(12)
"ZERO_RESULTS"
}
https: //maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=A&destination=B&key=AIzaSyAOW6tedtoxgX2VN0Qu256rriLHBJW5Vtk
```

-----------------------------DEBUG-----------------------------

The publisher of this plugin no longer supports it and seems to have the same problem on their demo page:
http://stern-taxi-fare.sternwebagency.com/fr/home/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Locate the Controller/stern_taxi_fare_functions.php
2. Go to line 881 and replace "origin=A" with "origin=Los Angeles"
3. Go to line 882 and replace "destination=B" with "destination=Las Vegas"

This will fix the stern taxi fare and enable the booking, Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Melanie.  Sure enough the form showed right back up after adding cities to the areas as mentioned.  I would recommend for auto-complete of addresses to also enable the:

Google Places API Web Service